# iter() function not accepting custom iterable object

Tags: python, iterator

I'm trying to pass my custom object `MyIter()` defined as follows into the `iter()` function
(using Python 3+)

```
class MyIter():
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

I'm not writing a `__next__` yet but just want to get back an iterable object
Clearly this doesn't work. My doubt is why can I pass something like a string into `iter()` function even when strings don't have a `__next__` object but not my custom object.

For example, `iter("sample")` returns a `str_iterator` even though `str` doesn't have a `__next__` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"123".__iter__()` returns a `str_iterator` object that implements `__next__()`.